# Not insert in update a value if undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a request body that can contain one or more elements. In my model present on database i want insert all elements in the body object, but if that is not present in run time I have an error because the value of a specific key is undefined.

In my model I have the attributes a,b,c,d.

In my request body I have: 
`{a: 1, b:1}`.

My insertion is 
`Models.findModel(req.params.id, {a: req.body.a, b:req.body.b, c: req.body.c, d: req.body.d}`
If I do this, I have an run time error cause d in a number and cannot be undefined.

I'm using Typescript and mongoose. Can I do something like req.body.a? and insert it only if is present?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
Models.findModel(req.params.id, _.pick(req.body, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
```

btw: Typescript is not doing any checks on runtime, only in transpilation time.